# How to download files of different types of computer format and without display to the user in Javascript or C#?

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a list of links, where each link corresponds to a different file that can be PDF, DOC, XLS, etc. obtained through a viewer on a jsp page. I have the link and the code for the file (documentId), but the way I'm doing it only downloads the last file in the list:

```js
// File 1
var url1 = "https://site.site.net/servlet/DocumentServlet?documentId=123456789&action=viewUncontrolledCopy#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0";

// File 2
var url2 = "https://site.site.net/servlet/DocumentServlet?documentId=987654321&action=viewUncontrolledCopy#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0";

window.location.assign (url1);
setTimeout (20000);
window.location.assign (url2);
```

I have already searched and could not find something that completely do what I need.

Comment: "download without displaying to the user" - do you mean without displaying to the user *first* or do you mean downloading to the user's PC without letting them know?  Hope it's not the later!

Comment: Have you tried: `window.open(url1)`

Comment: I have a feeling that `window.location.assign` will try to load them all in the current window, one after the other, so only the last one wins

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. But the answer with window.open below satisfied my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the window.open command

```
// File 1
var url1 = "https://site.site.net/servlet/DocumentServlet?documentId=123456789&action=viewUncontrolledCopy#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0";

// File 2
var url2 = "https://site.site.net/servlet/DocumentServlet?documentId=987654321&action=viewUncontrolledCopy#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0";

    window.open(url1);
    window.open(url2);
```

This will download the files by opening two new windows thus maintaining the first page open and the javascript running

Check here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_assign.asp

Location assign navigates to a new page.  This means that the rest of your javascript is not executed and only the first navigation occurs.